# Android NDK seekg broken?

Tags: android, c++, file-io, android-ndk

I am using the following code:

```
fileIn.seekg(12,std::ios::beg);
uint16_t data;
fileIn>>data;
LOG_D("app","file data=%u",data);
```

But what actually happens is it logs the value of offset I pass in seekg like in the given case it Logs

> **file data=12**

If i use

fileIn.seekg(**8**,std::ios::beg);
then it prints "file data=**8**"

in general it prints

> file data=**x** for fileIn.seekg(**x**,std::ios::beg);

its very mysterious to me ! I am using android ndk r10d c++ with eclipse for ARM thumb target

Comment: For any NDK question, you should say which NDK version you're using (which you've done), which STL you're using if it's an STL question (did you mean libc++ when you said c++?), and which API level you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that anything was actually read from the stream? I'm guessing you're just printing out garbage data.

Comment: Well If the file do exists as shown by if(fileIn) returning true and I know its more than 0 size